# How to compose a hierarchy of decorated classes without copying data

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have three classes which are hierarchically related:

- `Pattern`, which has the protected field `_panels` of type `std::vector<Panel>`.
- `Panel`, in turn, has a protected field `_edges`, which is of type `std::vector<Edge>`.
- `Edge`, finally, has a protected field `_verts`, which is of type `std::vector<Eigen::Vector2f>`.

I also have a pure virtual class `Renderable`, which has a pure virtual function `virtual void render()`. I want to create specialized versions of each of my three classes that inherit from `Renderable`, for example:

```
class VPattern : public Pattern, public Renderable
{
public:
    void render() { ... }
protected:
    ...
private:
    ...
}; // class VPattern
```

However, the `_panels` field will still contain instances of `Panel`, and not `VPanel`. This would mean that I would have to put the drawing logic for `Edge` and `Panel` in the draw function of `Pattern`, which is clearly not ideal.

Is there a different approach here that I'm not seeing that would avoid all this? Would using a wrapper class be a more suitable approach?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you can't have a `Drawable` virtual class that has a pure virtual function `draw()` that all its `drawable` descendents would implement?

```
public virtual struct Drawable {
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

public struct Edge : Drawable {
    void draw() {}
};

//...
```

Comment: Hi Bizkit, I'm sorry I might not have been clear. This is precisely what I have. However, if I have a VPattern which inherits from Renderable, I want all of the Panels in _panels to be drawn when I call VPattern::render. This is tricky, because the instances in _panels in VPattern are of type Panel, not VPanel. I'm wondering how to delegate the drawing of the panels to the instances in _panels, without having to copy all `Panels` to `VPanels` first, if that makes sense.

Comment: You need to specify which version of `render` you want. So when you implement VPattern::render(), you need it to go through the vector calling Panel::render.

Comment: Panel::render does not exist - VPanel::render does. But _panels is a vector of Panel, not of VPanel - this is the issue.